# Select data from three tables

Tags: mysql

First of all, those tables doesn't have any ties, so I can not use the `JOIN`.

I got three tables with another data, and I need to display all of the data from those three tables in one query with one result.

For example I got:

`Hot News` table that contains; `title`, `text`, `icon` rows.

`Bad News` table that contains; `title`, `text`, `icon` rows.

`Good News` table that contains; `title`, `text`, `icon` rows.

And I need to withdraw all news in one query. Is it possible?

Comment: @MikeChristensen, not me - evidently :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html):

```
SELECT title, text, icon FROM `Hot News`
UNION
SELECT title, text, icon FROM `Bad News`
UNION
SELECT title, text, icon FROM `Good News`
```

Note that UNION removes duplicates. If you want to keep duplicates, use UNION ALL instead.

Comment: To add on your example, if you use "SELECT *" the entire table structure will have to be identical, you can otherwise select individual columns, so long as they are equivilent.

Comment: I'm always receiving this error: `General error: 1271 Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION''`.

Comment: Hmm looks like your tables have different character sets?

Comment: It means some columns in other tables are different collations, some may be UTF-8, some ISO-8859-1, some may use case insensitive comparison, etc.

Comment: You can use [`COLLATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html) to specify the collation you want to use when you select. But it would be better to be consistent in your database design. And while we're on the subject of database design, you probably would be better storing this all in one table in the first place, and using a column to distinguish "Hot", "Good" and "Bad" news.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the UNION operator http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Title, Text Icon From HotNews
UNION ALL
SELECT Title, Text Icon From BadNews
UNION ALL
SELECT Title, Text Icon From GoodNews
```

Answer (score 1):

If I read your question right:

```
SELECT title, text, icon, 'News' AS type
FROM HotNews
UNION ALL
SELECT title, text, icon, 'Bad' AS type
FROM BadNews
UNION ALL
SELECT title, text, icon, 'Good' AS type
FROM GoodNews
```

By including `type` this means that whatever you are using to render this data to the user, can tell what kind of news it is.

Comment: Receiving this error: ` General error: 1271 Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'`, same as in Mark Byers answer.

Comment: @Cyclone, do you have the same character-sets across your tables?